# PHP mysql display query in 4 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to display this query result in 4 columns

```
<?php
$direction = $_POST['direction']; 
$sumword = $_POST['sumword'];  
$length = $_POST['length'];  
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","elsha","12q(5PSZ.");
$db = mysql_select_db("elsha",$con);
$query = "SELECT answer FROM words WHERE direction = '$direction' AND sumword = '$sumword' AND sumletter = '$length'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_error()) { 
  //check that no error has occurred first; take this out in production or make more graceful handling
  die(mysql_error());
}

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
  echo "No Results";
} else { 
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<img src="/images/'. $row['0'].'.jpg"><br> '. $row['0'].'<br>';
  }
}
?>
```

like this :

result1 result2 result3 result4

result5 result6 result7 result8

Comment: As nobody has mentioned it don't use the mysql functions anymore they are deprecated and in PHP 7.0 are deleted use mysqli or PDO instead. Also when handling user input like above use prepared statements because now your code is open for SQL injection

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<img src="/images/'. $row['0'].'.jpg"> ';
    $i++;
    if($i % 4 == 1 && $i!=1){
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flag like

```
$flag=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     if(($flag%4)==0) {
       echo '<tr>';
     } 
     echo '<td><img src="/images/'. $row['0'].'.jpg"><br> '. $row['0'].'</td>';
    if(($flag%4)==3) {
      echo '</tr>';
      $flag=-1;
     } 
     $flag++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your while with the following code. try this

```
$a=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($a%4==0) {
        echo '<img src="/images/'. $row['0'].'.jpg">'.    $row['0'].'<br>';
    } //4th line with break
    else {
        echo '<img src="/images/'. $row['0'].'.jpg"> '. $row['0'].' '; // prints first 3 lines 
    }
    $a=$a+1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to display the image name too below the image. Try this:

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo '<div class="imgs">';
       echo '<img src="/images/'. $row['0'].'.jpg"><br> '. $row['0'];
       echo '</div>';
       if ($i === 4) {
           echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
           $i = 1;
       } else {
           $i++;
       }
 }
```

and then style div's

```
.imgs {
  float: left;
  /* other styles */
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: almost right, but the first row has 5 columns and the rest 4

Comment: @BudiAndug hm, that's unexpected. did you assign `$i` as 1 before the `while` ?